# Problems with object index

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have a firebase database that users can upload entries too. Let's say that the user uploads three entries and then deletes the middle entry before the object index was 0 1 2 but now it's
0 2 which causes my code to crash. Does anybody know how to refactor a object with an index of 0 2 to something like 0 1 so my code doesn't crash.

Comment: Share a snippet of what you tried

Comment: Pls share more details. What firebase db are you using. What code have you tried and all.

Comment: I'm using the firebase realtime database. Here's some of the things i tried. 1 all sorts of combinations of shifting and unshifting the object. 2 trying decrease each index by one. 3 mapping the object to an array

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, we can handle by using `splice` method on array.

```js
var arr = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}];
arr.splice(1, 1);
console.log('New Array :',arr, '\nFirst Object :',arr[0], '\nSecond Object :',arr[1]);
```